# FileStream.Read() doesn't work with offset more than 0 in c#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I am working on a file transferring system in **c#**. The client reads the file into partitions and sends each partition to the server.

Each partition is 4096 bytes except for last partition which is the rest of the bytes. Data is sent over a **TCP** socket.

The problem is in the `FileStream.Read()` function because whenever offset is greater than 0, the function raises a `System.ArgumentException`. Here is the code:

```
string fileSize = "0";
FileStream f = null;
try
{
    f = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    fileSize = f.Length.ToString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{ }
// send partition count to server
int partitionCount = int.Parse(fileSize) / 4096;
int lastPartitionSize = (int.Parse(fileSize) - (partitionCount * 4096));
Thread.Sleep(20);
sendData(partitionCount.ToString());
Thread.Sleep(20);
sendData(lastPartitionSize.ToString());
Thread.Sleep(20);
for (int i = 0; i < (partitionCount); i++)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    int offset = (4096 * i);
    Console.WriteLine("Partition: " + (i+1) + "  |  Offset: " + offset + "  |  Bytes Left: " + (f.Length - (4096*i)));
    f.Read(data, offset, 4096); // problem is RIGHT HERE
    sendRawData(data);
}
byte[] lastData = new byte[lastPartitionSize];
f.Read(lastData, (4096 * partitionCount), lastPartitionSize);
sendRawData(lastData);
```

Comment: For future question please read [MCVE] guidance carefully. There is way too much code to show that you were not able to understand [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) article - one line like `f.Read(new byte[4096], 4096 * 3, 4096);` would be enough and actually demonstrate that you've tried to find solution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov okay, thanks for letting me know, I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN:

> *offset*
>
> The byte offset in **array** at which the read bytes will be placed.

So your offset should always be zero

Comment: so it is not a position of a byte from which file will be read? welp, I guess I learned something new today, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the `Position` property of `Filestream`

Comment: seems to kind of work now, but it still throws an exception before reading the last partition. still throws the `System.ArgumentException`.

Comment: Yeah you may need to calculate the exact size of the last block of data and just read that into a new array

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing in the last 3 lines of code

Comment: Wait, never mind, that is another problem but your suggestion solved the original problem, thanks a lot!